# Project point from point cloud to Image in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to project a point from 3D to 2D in OpenCV with C++. At the Moment, I'm using cv::projectPoints() but it's just not working out.

But first things first. I'm trying to write a program, that finds an intersection between a point cloud and a line in space. So I calibrated two cameras, did rectification and matching using SGBM. Finally I projected the disparity map to 3d using reprojectTo3D(). That all works very well and in meshlab, I can visualize my point cloud.

After that I wrote an algorithm to find the intersection between the point cloud and a line which I coded manually. That works fine, too. I found a point in the point cloud about 1.5 mm away from the line, which is good enough for the beginning. So I took this point and tried to project it back to the image, so I could mark it. But here is the problem.

Now the point is not inside the image anymore. As I took an intersection in the middle of the image, this is not possible. I think the problem could be in the coordinate systems, as I don't know in which coordinate system the point cloud is written (left camera, right camera or something else).

My projectPoints function looks like:

```
projectPoints(intersectionPoint3D, R, T, cameraMatrixLeft, distortionCoeffsLeft, intersectionPoint2D, noArray(), 0);
```

R and T are the rotation and translation from one camera to another (got that from stereoCalibrate). Here might be my mistake, but how can I fix it? I also tried to set these to (0,0,0) but it doesn't work either. Also I tried to transform the R Matrix using Rodrigues to a vector. Still same problem.

I'm sorry if this has been asked before, but I'm not sure how to search for this problem. I hope my text is clear enought to help me... if you need more information, I will gladly provide it.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure in what coordinate system your pointcloud is... but R and T are the position of the camera relative to the origin of your point cloud. If the pointcloud is already in the origin, then R and T are not needed. If it is in the model point of view (origin in the center of the pointcloud) then you need an R an T that represents the pose of the camera for this origin.... Take a look to [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/4379/from-3d-point-cloud-to-disparity-map/) it explains how to use your Q matrix to go to from 3D to disparity map

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That helps a lot already. But now I'm wondering how I could get the coords of the actual left (rectified) image of that point. So am I correct, if I say that to get the coordinates of a certain point in the left image, I could just take the coordinates of the disparity map of that point. And to get the coordinates of the right image I take the disparity coords and add the actual disparity at that point? I'm not sure if it's clear what I try to explain. What is the default "base" coordinate system of a disparity map, created with stereo SGBM? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You have a 3D point and you want to get the corresponding 2D location of it right? If you have the camera calibration matrix (3x3 matrix), you will be able to project the point to the image

```
cv::Point2d get2DFrom3D(cv::Point3d p, cv::Mat1d CameraMat)
{
    cv::Point2d pix;
    pix.x = (p.x * CameraMat(0, 0)) / p.z + CameraMat(0, 2);
    pix.y = ((p.y * CameraMat(1, 1)) / p.z + CameraMat(1, 2));
    return pix;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I've realized I've got a more basic problem here. I'll open up new question for that. Thanks for your help.